# How to make a post request with the Python requests library?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, cassandra

I am using the following filters in Postman to make a POST request in a Web API but I am unable to make a simple POST request in Python with the requests library.

**First**, I am sending a POST request to this URL (http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets) with the following filters in Postman applied to the Body, with the raw and JSON(application/json) options selected.

```
Filters in Postman

{
  "filter": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "field": "RCA_Assigned_Date",
        "operator": "gte",
        "value": "2017-05-31 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "field": "RCA_Assigned_Date",
        "operator": "lte",
        "value": "2017-06-04 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "field": "T_Subcategory",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": "Temporary Degradation"
      },
      {
        "field": "Issue_Status",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": "Queued"
      }],
     "logic": "and"
    }
}
```

The database where the data is stored is Cassandra and according to the following links [Cassandra not equal operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925525/cassandra-not-equal-operator), [Cassandra OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255734/cassandra-between-order-by-operations?rq=1),
 [Cassandra Between order by operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309198/cassandra-cql-or-operator), Cassandra does not support the **NOT EQUAL TO**, **OR**, **BETWEEN** operators, so there is no way I can filter the URL with these operators except with **AND**.

**Second**, I am using the following code to apply a simple filter with the requests library.

```
import requests
payload = {'field':'T_Subcategory','operator':'neq','value':'Temporary Degradation'}
url = requests.post("http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets",data=payload)
```

But what I've got is the complete data of tickets instead of only those that are not temporary degradation.

**Third**, the system is actually working but we are experiencing a delay of 2-3 mins to see the data. The logic goes as follows: *We have 8 users and we want to see all the tickets per user that are not temporary degradation, then we do*:

```
def get_json():
    if user_name == "user 001":
        with urllib.request.urlopen(
    "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets?user_name=user&001",timeout=15) as url:
            complete_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    elif user_name == "user 002":
        with urllib.request.urlopen(             
    "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets?user_name=user&002",timeout=15) as url:
            complete_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    return complete_data

def get_tickets_not_temp_degradation(start_date,end_date,complete_):
    return Counter([k['user_name'] for k in complete_data if start_date < dateutil.parser.parse(k.get('DateTime')) < end_date and k['T_subcategory'] != 'Temporary Degradation'])
```

Basically, we get the whole set of tickets from the current and last year, then we let Python to filter the complete set by user and so far there are only 10 users which means that this process is repeated 10 times and makes me no surprise to discover why we get the delay...

My questions is how can I fix this problem of the requests library? I am using the following link [Requests library documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) as a tutorial to make it working but it just seems that my payload is not being read.

Comment: I've had luck using the `json` keyword arg in place of `data` when using JSON-ish data.

Comment: replace `data=payload` with `json=payload`

Comment: I've got no luck by changing the data=payload to json=payload :(

Comment: So **does the Postman query work** or does it not?

Comment: Your question is also confusing. If cassandra doesn't support certain filter operations, then that's not a `requests` limitation. You can only send queries that cassandra supports, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: My postman query works. I have tried the proposed solutions from the comments but they were not successful. The last resource (and one that I would not like to do) would be to download all the JSON data and store it locally in a SQL DB..... but I was expecting that the Python library could work.

Comment: @AlejandroRamos: you never made the same JSON body, though, you sent a different filter.

Comment: The Postman filter works, so this indicates me that the not equal operations, or operations, between queries work..

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can I make the JSON body?

Comment: @AlejandroRamos: also, the `urllib.requests.urlopen` URLs look malformed; `user_name=user&001` is two separate fields. Are you sure that's not `user_name=user+001` instead?

Comment: user_name=user+001 works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Postman request is a JSON body. Just reproduce that same body in Python. Your Python code is not sending JSON, nor is it sending the same data as your Postman sample.

For starters, sending a dictionary via the `data` arguments encodes that dictionary to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form, not JSON. Secondly, you appear to be sending a single filter.

The following code replicates your Postman post exactly:

```
import requests

filters = {"filter": {
    "filters": [{
        "field": "RCA_Assigned_Date",
        "operator": "gte",
        "value": "2017-05-31 00:00:00"
    }, {
        "field": "RCA_Assigned_Date",
        "operator": "lte",
        "value": "2017-06-04 00:00:00"
    }, {
        "field": "T_Subcategory",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": "Temporary Degradation"
    }, {
        "field": "Issue_Status",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": "Queued"
    }],
    "logic": "and"
}}

url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets"
response = requests.post(url, json=filters)
```

Note that `filters` is a *Python* data structure here, and that it is passed to the `json` keyword argument. Using the latter does two things:

- Encode the Python data structure to JSON (producing the exact same JSON value as your raw Postman body value).
- Set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` (as you did in your Postman configuration by picking the `JSON` option in the dropdown menu after picking `raw` for the body).

`requests` is otherwise *just an HTTP API*, it can't make Cassandra do any more than any other HTTP library. The `urllib.request.urlopen` code sends `GET` requests, and are trivially translated to `requests` with:

```
def get_json():
    url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets"
    response = requests.get(url, params={'user_name': user}, timeout=15)    
    return response.json()
```

I removed the `if` branching and replaced that with using the `params` argument, which translates a dictionary of key-value pairs to a correctly encoded URL query (passing in the user name as the `user_name` key).

Note the `json()` call on the response; this takes care of decoding JSON data coming back from the server. This still takes long, you are not filtering the Cassandra data much here.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the `json` attribute instead of data. It handles the dumping for you.

```
import requests

data = {'user_name':'user&001'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets/"
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Update, answer for question 3. Is there a reason you are using urllib? I’d use python requests as well for this request.

```
import requests

def get_json():
    r = requests.get("http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets”, params={"user_name": user_name.replace(" ", "&")})

    return r.json

# not sure what you’re doing here, more context/code example would help
def get_tickets_not_temp_degradation(start_date, end_date, complete_):
    return Counter([k['user_name'] for k in complete_data if start_date < dateutil.parser.parse(k.get('DateTime')) < end_date and k['T_subcategory'] != 'Temporary Degradation'])
```

Also, is the username really supposed to be `user+001` and not `user&001` or `user 001`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use requests library as follows:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'field':'T_Subcategory','operator':'neq','value':'Temporary Degradation'}
url = requests.post("http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets",data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: I've got something new here: `Message: The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.`

Comment: I managed to solve this by using the following: `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'text/plain'}` and then `r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)` but it just seems that posts retrieves all data.

Comment: You could actually just specify `json={“whoami”: “I’m a python dict”}` instead of `data=json.dumps...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending user in url, use it through post, but its depend upon how end points are implemented. You can try the below code :

```
import requests
from json import dumps

data = {'user_name':'user&001'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/a/api/rows/cat/ect/tickets/"
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=dumps(data))
```