# i made a python script to login but it always reply error

Tags: php, python

this is a script i made it logs on to a php site but it always show error
i teated cookie lib that dont seem to work out for me any idea to fix it

```py
import requests
url = 'http://my local site/some.php'
password = "foo"

r = requests.post(url,password)
print (r.content)
```

this is php script i wrote

````php
<?php
$password=$_POST['password'];


if($password=='foo')
{
    echo"{"status":"true","Message":"Key Found."}";

}
else
{
    echo "{"status":"false","Message":"No Key Found."}";
}
?>```
````

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201628/how-to-make-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library

Comment: That is not the correct way to submit form data via post.  Perhaps you should read the requests documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'password': "foo"}  
r = requests.post(url,data)
```

You should read the `requests` documentation. https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request